# Reading multiple excel files and writting it to multiple excel files in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have written code  where it is reading excel file and then after processing required function I want to write it to Excel file . Now I have done this for one excel file . and now my question is when I want to do it for multiple excel file that is reading multiple excel file and then output should be also in multiple excel file how will I apply for loop here  so I get separate output excel file for each input file

Following is my code

```
from ParallelP import *
import time,json
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
     __ip__ = "ip/"
     __op__ = "op/"
     __excel_file_name__ = __ip__ + '80chars.xlsx'
     __prediction_op__ = __op__ + basename(__excel_file_name__) + "_processed.xlsx"
     df = pd.read_excel(__excel_file_name__)
     start_time = time.time()
     df_preprocessed = run(df)
     print("Time Needed to execute all data is {0} seconds".format((time.time() - start_time)))
     print("Done...")
     df_preprocessed.to_excel(__prediction_op__)
```

Comment: what problem are you facing

Comment: How do I write for loop  for  reading multiple excel files and output  in to multiple excel files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to stick to your example and just expand it as I would do it. The below example is untested and does not mean that it is the best way to do it!

```
from ParallelP import *
import time,json
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path  # Handles directory paths -> less error prone than manually sticking together paths

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __ip__ = "ip/"
    __op__ = "op/"

    # Get a list of all excel files in a given directory
    excel_file_list = [f for f in os.listdir(__ip__) if f.endswith('.xlsx')]

    # Loop over the list and process each excel file seperately
    for excel_file in excel_file_list:
        excel_file_path = Path(__ip__, excel_file)  # Create the file path
        df = pd.read_excel(str(excel_file))  # Read the excel file to data frame
        start_time = time.time()
        df_preprocessed = run(df)  # Run your routine
        print("Time Needed to execute all data is {0} seconds".format((time.time() - start_time)))
        print("Done...")

        # Create the output file name
        prediction_output_file_name = '{}__processed.xlsx'.format(str(excel_file_path.resolve().stem))

        # Create the output file path
        prediction_output_file_path = str(Path(__op__, prediction_output_file_name))

        # Write the output to the excel file
        df_preprocessed.to_excel(prediction_output_file_path)
```

Sidenote: I have to mention that your variable names feel like a misuse of the __ . These 'dunder' functions are special and indicate that they have a meaning for python ([see for example here](https://dbader.org/blog/python-dunder-methods)). Please, just name your variables `input_dir` and `output_dir` instead of `__ip__` and `__op__`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I do have some code i wrote. Maybe you can alter this for your requirements.

```
# This is where your input file should be
in_folder = 'input/xls/file/folder'

# This will be your output folder
out_folder = 'output/xls/file/folder'

if not os.path.exists(out_folder):
    os.makedirs(out_folder)


file_exist = False
dir_list = os.listdir(in_folder)
for xlfile in dir_list:
    if xlfile.endswith('.xlsx') or xlfile.endswith('.xls'):
        file_exist = True
        str_file = os.path.join(in_folder, xlfile)
        #work_book = load_workbook(filename=str_file)
        #work_sheet = work_book['qa']

        #Do ur work hear with excel

        #out_Path = os.path.join(out_folder,)

        #and output it to the out_Path

if not file_exist:
    print('cannot find any valid excel file in the folder ' + in_folder)
```

Comment: Will I get seperate excel file for each input excel file?

Comment: This will give you separate excel file to read.  'str_file' and if you save each inside the loop, you should get separate files. You can try calling your method in loop.